# Image URL issue

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, formula

I have formula field which displays image on Quote pdf where image URL is in text field. Since '&' is getting replaced by '&amp;' am getting broken image. I am using Substitute function which isn't helping! Is there a way fix this?
IMAGE( SUBSTITUTE(Advisor_picture__c, "&amp;","&") , "pic", 100,100)

Advisor_picture__c : "https://xxx.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=ORIGINAL_Png&amp;versionId=0687f000001BpzV&amp;operationContext=CHATTER&amp;contentId=05T7f000009rzKY"

Text field is fed by Flow.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the text field to URL field, it worked!!